# Django-hstore and admin widget: way to unsort hstore data

Tags: python, django, django-admin, hstore, django-hstore

I'm use Django-hstore library, and there is pretty admin widget. The subject table store computer's components, something like this:

```
class Component(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_page = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text='url to pruduct page')
    <...>
    data = hstore.DictionaryField(blank=True)

    def load_cpu_data(self):
        if self.product_page:
            info = cpu_data(self.product_page)
            if info:  # info is a SortedDict with proper order
                for key, value in info.items():
                    self.data[key] = value
                self.save()
```

Next, I get data from [`cpu-world.com`](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%203000+%20-%20ADA3000DIK4BI%20(ADA3000BIBOX).html) about necessary CPU and I have following inline data in admin:

[image]

Look great, but sorting alphabetically instead logical, in order of loading data into database in `load_cpu_data` model method. Example of proper order, like on cpu-world:

```
Family
Model number
Frequency
Socket
Microarchitecture
Processor core
Manufacturing process
Data width
The number of CPU cores
The number of threads
Integrated graphics
Thermal Design Power
```

Is there technique, or trick, or something to help me show data in desired sequence? For example, I found python [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) data type, which similar to what I need. But apparently hstore inner structure mess data order.

Answer (score 0):

according to [the hstore docs, hstore itself is not ordered](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html):

> The order of the pairs is not significant (and may not be reproduced on output). Whitespace between pairs or around the => sign is ignored. Double-quote keys and values that include whitespace, commas, =s or >s. To include a double quote or a backslash in a key or value, escape it with a backslash.